# How can I use .gitignore properly?

Tags: git, commit, gitignore

This is how my .gitignore file looks like:

```
/.env
/public/bundles/
/var/
/vendor/
/public/data/
/public/data/data.json
```

I added the `data.json` file later to the `.gitignore` file and now I have the problem that git does not accept the file as ignored. So whenever I make a change on the file, git is listing the file `public/data/data.json` in uncommited changes...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a file is already tracked by git, it will be that way no matter what .gitignore says. If you want to stop tracking it, try `git rm --cached public/data/data.json`. This will remove file from git, but not from the filesystem.

Comment: Do I have to do this on my local as well as server?

Comment: Generally with git you always do things locally, commit them and then push somewhere (e.g. to the server) if you wish.